# How to align the text description if it includes image beside it?

Tags: php, css, string

I want to align the text description on my page such that if anybody puts a string of long length without space, the string should break where image starts & following text should come on the next line.
I've uploaded an image what actually is happening.

[image]

Here's my code::

```
<div class="right">
<div class="all_content"  style="float: left; height:auto; padding:30px ;color:white;font-size:30px;line-height: 40px;word-break: break-word">  
    <div class="heading" style="width:760px">
        <?php
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $RS = Run("SELECT firstname,lastname,description,img FROM info WHERE id='$id'");
        while($ROW = GetRow($RS))
        {
            echo $ROW['firstname'];
            echo " ";
            echo $ROW['lastname'];
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="rt">
        <?php
        $path = 'images/uploaded/'.$ROW['img'];
        if(file_exists($path) && $ROW['img'] != "")
        {  
        ?>
        <img src="images/uploaded/<?php echo $ROW['img']?>"  width="380px" align="center" border="0" />
        <?php
        }
        else
            echo '<img src="images/uploaded/placeholder.png"  width="350px" align="center" border="0" />';
        ?>          
    </div>
        <?php
            echo "</br>";
            echo $ROW['description'];
            }
        ?>
</div>
```

CSS::

```
.right{
width:1260px;
height:1050px;
float:left;
background-color:#1e285d;
}
.heading{
width:830px;
height:100px;
float:left;
font-size: 100px;
line-height: 30px;
margin-bottom:35px;
}
.rt{
width:350px;
height:auto;
float:right;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
font-size: 40px;
}
```

I don't want that string below the image. It should start below the heading immediately.
I know that nobody would type such stupid word but still I want to know what to do.

Comment: Just put a `div` around the description with a width of 350px

Comment: @JoeAxon it divides the description & image in two different columns.

Comment: Do you want the description to flow around the bottom of the image?

Comment: @MarcAudet yes, that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property word-break
    http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Comment: The string that you are showing contains not a single space(long word with no breaks).Is it always like this.Have you tried adding a space in between

Comment: I know that's very unusual string. I've tried with adding space in it. It works as per my condition when I add space in between. I want to know what to do in such conditions.

Comment: Have you tried giving float: left to divs all_content, heading and rt

Comment: its already float:right to all_content & heading, also tried for 'rt' but doesn't work. I saw that fiddle but it doesn't contain an image.

Comment: Try giving float:left to rt too(float:left to all three divs and adjust.It works normally) and use word-break property

Answer (score 0):

Place the image inside the text and give the style `float:right;` to the image and `word-break:break-all;` to the texr

Comment: yeah, that's what I've in my code, that class 'rt' is for image itself & which is inside the div meant for text.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to use it.

Comment: just add your code there, save it, give me the link. Simple as that.

Comment: but how to load the image in it?

Comment: adjust the width, otherwise everything ok. here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaSB9/)

Comment: hey thanks, I saw that but its not helping me, I'll try on it later.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to put a width on the description you would have to manually split the string in php or in javascript.

In PHP:

```
echo wordwrap($description, 78, '- ');
```

That won't be very pretty and it won't work well with non-monospaced fonts and obviously the `78` would be different for you. It also assumes a fixed width on the page.

If you wanted something better you could use javascript to iteratively add characters to an element until its width goes over the maximum allowed and then add in a space.